# Problems with pausing using Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I have this issue where pausing introduced into my code doesn't execute in a serial manner. For example:

```
doSomething();
Thread.sleep(1000); //try and catch omitted for simplicity
doSomethingElse();
```

When I execute the code, it runs as if it was ordered:

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
doSomething();
doSomethingElse();
```

What am I missing about the nature of threaded code that could cause this re-organization at runtime? This doesn't always happen, just with some code that proceeds `Thread.sleep()`. Without getting too specific with my `doSomething()` code I was wondering if someone could explain the types of behavior that may exist in `doSomething()` that could cause this. I'm thinking that there is some threaded code in `doSomething()` that I don't see because it is obscured in the library. So, what I thinking is a serial process is actually running in parallel with some other thread(s).

Ideas?

Comment: how do you know that it runs in the unexpected manner (sleep, dosomethign, dosomethingelse)? I can assure you that it does not and that sleep happens between the methods, so we have to figure out why you believe otherwise. Of course the doSomething may invoke some code in another threads but still, the doSomethingElse will not start before the sleep is finished.

Comment: I agree with @Zielu. If your `doSomething` prints to `System.out` perhaps it's not being flushed instantly and fooling you into thinking it's happening after the `sleep`.

Comment: Yeah, I probably wasn't clear, but the execution order is definitely doSomething(); --> Thread.sleep(1000); --> doSomethingElse();, however, the output of the methods (which happens to be the updating a screen buffer then refreshing the buffer in a terminal ala some low level code I'm using in a library) makes it appear that the order is  Thread.sleep(1000); -->doSomething(); --> doSomethingElse();. The order of the transfer from the screen buffer to the Terminal  is what appears out of order.